# Geany text editor - caret or cursor

Tags: geany

How can I set the caret style in Geany editor to look **bold**, something similar to the terminal caret style or to enhance its observability. Any tweaks available. Thanks for any suggestion as the default look is difficult to point out quickly due to its very thin look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug-report/request dealing with this, which apparently has not been addressed: [#527 Caret options](http://sourceforge.net/p/geany/feature-requests/527/) :

> As of 0.20, Geany's caret (AKA cursor) is drawn as a 1-pixel vertical bar in insert mode, and as a 2-pixel horizontal bar in overwrite mode, and there's an option to decide whether it blinks or not.
>
> While this makes sense, I would prefer to be able to choose what kind of cursor (horizontal, vertical or block) shows in every mode and to decide how fast the cursor blinks. (Due to nostalgia, I prefer horizontal cursors for inserting, and block cursors for replacing, and I prefer a faster blinking cursor which is more easily visible and somehow encourages working faster.)

In the followup comments, a [workaround](http://git.geany.org/geany/tree/data/filetypes.common#n45) is suggested:

```
# colour of the caret(the blinking cursor), only first and third argument is interpreted
# set the third argument to true to change the caret into a block caret
caret=caret
```

as well as a [followup request](http://sourceforge.net/p/scintilla/feature-requests/1037/) to the Scintilla developers, which  has had no action.

Comment: In my `~/.config/geany/filedefs/filetypes.common`, I have `caret_width=3` which is the maximum width permissible. Geany 1.26. In my gtk2 theme's gtkrc, I set `GtkWidget::cursor-color = "red"`.

Answer (score 0):

I changed that via Tools > Configuration Files > filetypes.common
and then restarted Geany but nothing changed.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/418954)

Answer (score 0):

**Geany cursor, aka caret**

After activating the '**Vimode**' plugin (Menu → Tools → Plugin Manager),
the vertical line cursor/caret has changed to an unblinking block
exactly like in the VIM editor. 
To return to the initial shape of the cursor,
**deactivate the plugin 'Vimode'**.

If you still want to change the vertical caret into a block caret,
go to
Menu → Tools → Configuration Files → filetypes.common,
find the line `caret=caret`
and add `;;true` to the end of the line like this:

```
caret=caret;;true
```

---

If you want to change the width of caret to look **bold**,
change '1' in the `caret_width=1` line to '2' or the maximum '3':

```
 caret_width=3
```

Attention: if you specify '0', the caret will disappear.

You don't need to restart Geany in order to apply these changes.