# Can I change the text insertion icon system-wide?

Tags: environment-variables

System-wide, I desperately want to make my text-selection icon a cross-hair.

It might have been a huge laugh decades ago, choosing an oversize capital (upper-case) letter `I` for Insert (geddit?), but it's not just a bad choice, it's the WRONG choice.

Do I have to petition Mint Linux?
Or is it user-fixable?

Comment: the text insertion icon is called a *caret*, by the way.

Comment: In addition to all the sensible things @MarcusMüller says in his answer, I want to say that I believe the current design to be better than a cross-hair. It's not seldom that you need to edit text and want to insert something in the middle, then it's quite nice to have a clear marking of a point in a line, that doesn't cover parts of the text around it.

Comment: Sorry,  I meant the text selection (audio selectio in Audacity) icon. Original post has now been edited. But the same dumb serif capital-I-looking thing is also used is also used to signify the text insertion point in bash, xed, Libre Office and Firefox browser. If I want to highlight text on this webpage, I'm stuck with the same easy-to-lose daft I-beam.

Comment: The word caret comes from the French. It looks a bit like a Chinese hat from a cartoon. It's too high on the platten to use as a typesetter's insertion  mark. On British keyboards, it's usually obtained with Shift+6 (6 just below F6). ^

Comment: @PhilHeadford If you mean the mouse cursor when over a text field (or a text area), that is easily done by modifying your X cursor theme. How exactly to do that depends on what DE (desktop environment), if any are you using. There is a page on Arch wiki about [cursor themes](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Cursor_themes), which can be adjusted for use on other distros with minor modifications, mostly related to the Arch-specific package manager and packages.

Comment: To repeat what I wrote in my comment to the deleted answer, the solution would most probably be as simple as finding the cursor theme directory and copying the cursor file (likely named _crosshair_) over the file for text editing cursor (likely named _text_) and restarting X. Of course, creating a backup of the overwritten cursor file would be useful if one ever wants to roll back to the previous state.

Comment: Related: https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/83432

Answer (score 1):

That's not up to a distribution to address; different programs use different methods of drawing *carets*. So, you need to address that with GTK/GDK, Qt, WX, Chromium, Gecko, LFTK, TK, … There's no "system wide" here; some might make this configurable, others don't.

In other words: you need to find the programs you want to change, figure out what toolkit they use to draw their UI, and figure out how to change the insert *caret* for that specific library.

Petitioning anyone will not help you; I think you know pretty well that you're have a niche demand. (That'd be different if your change was actually aimed at making things easier to read at large large sizes for visually impaired people; but "I want a cross-hair" is not an accessibility improvement.) So, you can of course ask projects for help figuring out how, but if there's code to be written to support that, you'll be the one that will have to supply that code, most probably: "just" adding this one small future makes your life a tiny bit better for free, but it will mean there's new code that needs to be maintained for years and decades to come, so any well-led project will be hesitant to add that – *feature sprawl* is a very real danger to being able to keep a project alive.

Just as an example, you might have already stumbled across this very similar question on here: [Geany text editor - caret or cursor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/260322/geany-text-editor-caret-or-cursor)

Comment: Thanks to Macus for his time and effort. I can assure him it was worthwhile. I'm 76, and my eyes are not improving. I have used systems which employ a fine cross-hair as a selector. It's way superior. And obligatory for 2D or 3D design draughting. Sad to hear that there's no systen-wide fix for this blunder.